# How does google-drive-ocamlfuse start its service during system startup?

Tags: google-drive

When logging to my profile, I have noticed that google-drive is present in Files.
I checked startup programs - no google-drive on list. I also checked fstab - not found it. Checked also sysv-rc-conf - nothing. After reboot it is still visible and present in mtab. My question is: how does the system start it during startup? Where from? How can I block it and start it only manually via terminal when needed?

Comment: From a terminal, try: `sudo systemctl list-dependencies --reverse google-drive-ocamlfuse`. That will list systemd targets which will start that service.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the name itself provides a huge hint. The term fuse, on certain Linux opperating systems, has a special meaning. This is no exception. Your application is being "glued" to the main filesystem using [FUSE technology](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15213-s07/lectures/15-filesys/index.html).

On a general level, you can think of FUSEd files as being mounted. This means that they are not really a part of the system at all. A link gets created so that any time you access the FUSEd parent directory, you automatically traverse the link. This makes it seem like it is one cbig system.

Getting back to your question, any processes that involve FUSE technology are generally handled by the FUSE daemon. The name of this daemon is **fuse.ko**. The starting and stopping the loading of these files / filesystems falls into this category. Therefore: to answer your question specifically:

The application that mounts the `google-drive-ocamlfuse` filesystem is `fuse.ko`, otherwise known as the `FUSE daemon.`